# TypeScript Generic types for a chat message

Tags: typescript, generics

How to constraint type of a property based on another property value ?

```ts
interface User {
  name: string;
}

type Kind = 'text' | 'image';

interface TextMessage {
  text: string;
}

interface ImageMessage {
  src: string;
  alt?: string;
}

type MessageType = TextMessage | ImageMessage

interface Message {
  user: User;
  kind: Kind;
  // But, message of Kind 'text' must have a content of type TextMessage
  content: MessageType;
}
```

I need to constraint the form of the `content` key depending on the property `type` passed to ths same object.
I know I need to use Generics but I can't figure where.

Example:

```ts
const textMsg: Message = {
  user: {
    name: 'bot',
  },
  kind: 'text',
  content: {
    // Not allowed, there is only allowed to have the `text` property
    src: 'https://example.com/img.png'
  }
}

const textMsg: Message = {
  user: {
    name: 'bot',
  },
  kind: 'image',
  content: {
    // Allowed, this is an ImageMessage
    src: 'https://example.com/img.png'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) type that is either a `TextMessage` or an `ImageMessage`. I'll use a base interface `AnyMessage` that specifies the `kind` field as *discriminant* for all extending messages, including the constraint of type `Kind`:

```
type Kind = 'text' | 'image';

interface AnyMessage {
    // This is where other common props such as 'user' go too
    kind: Kind;
}
```

From this interface you can create the extended message types.

The idea of a discriminated union like this is to override the type constraint of `kind: Kind` with any string literal that is in the type `Kind`, to tie that name to the specific additional properties that the extensions have:

```
interface TextMessage extends AnyMessage {
    kind: 'text'; // <- That's the TYPE 'text'
    text: string;
}

interface ImageMessage extends AnyMessage {
    kind: 'image';
    src: string;
    alt?: string;
}

// This is the type to use for the actual messages:
type Message = TextMessage | ImageMessage
```

A quick test of the types shows that you can no longer have properties unknown to the specific message types:

```
// OK
const m1: TextMessage = { kind: 'text', text: 'foo bar baz' };

// OK
const m2: ImageMessage = { kind: 'image', src: 'foo bar baz' };

// Error: Type '{ kind: "text"; src: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TextMessage'
const m3: TextMessage = { kind: 'text', src: 'foo bar baz' };

// Error: Type '{ kind: "image"; text: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ImageMessage'
const m4: ImageMessage = { kind: 'image', text: 'foo bar baz' }
```

I left out the fact that your messages have a `content` property in which to put all the specific keys of the message data. There's multiple ways to do that, the easiest is to just specify the content property in each extended message, eg:

```
interface ImageMessage extends AnyMessage {
    kind: 'image';
    content: {
        src: string;
        alt?: string;
    }
}
```

You could also have the content key in the `AnyMessage` base interface, and have  parameterised types `T` for the `Kind` and `U` for the content property:

```
interface AnyMessage<T extends Kind, U extends object = {}> {
    kind: T;
    content: U;
}
```

Now the type passed to AnyMessage is automatically going to be in a `content` property of the message-type. You can use this as follows -- it now makes more sense to have `type` aliases instead of `interface`s for `TextMessage` and `ImageMessage`, because they already give their additional properties as `U`:

```
type TextMessage = AnyMessage<'text', {
    text: string;
}>

type ImageMessage = AnyMessage<'image', {
    src: string;
    alt?: string;
}>

type Message = TextMessage | ImageMessage

// OK
const m1: TextMessage = { kind: 'text', content: { text: 'foo bar baz' } };
// OK
const m2: ImageMessage = { kind: 'image', content: { src: 'foo bar baz' }};

// Error
const m3: TextMessage = { kind: 'text', content: { src: 'foo bar baz' } };
// Error
const m4: ImageMessage = { kind: 'image', content: { text: 'foo bar baz' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
type Message = {
  user: User;
} & ({
  kind: 'text';
  content: TextMessage;
} | {
  kind: 'image';
  content: ImageMessage;
})
```

Comment: Oh yes, exactly ! But isn't there a way to do it with Generics ? I'd have a mapper with `[K in Kind]: MessageType`